# Order and spaces in shell command using std input/output redirections

Tags: bash, socat

Sorry I didn't use shell scripts for a while. In tutorial ["How to run Openthread border router"](https://openthread.io/guides/border-router/docker/run)

steps provided:

[Set up a bidirectional data stream with **socat**](https://openthread.io/guides/border-router/docker/run#set_up_a_bidirectional_data_stream)

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
2018/09/06 09:58:29 socat[242994] N PTY is /dev/pts/2
2018/09/06 09:58:29 socat[242994] N PTY is /dev/pts/7
2018/09/06 09:58:29 socat[242994] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [7,7]
```

Make a note of the two serial ports in the output.

then there is CLI command:

```
~/openthread/output/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ot-ncp-ftd 1 \
> /dev/pts/2 < /dev/pts/2
```

Entering these commands doesn't give correct result. What is the meaning of last command from shell programming perspective (I believe it redirects input/output of program )? Is the last command correct (note - it uses the same port 2)? In my case program obtains more then 4 args (I see in debugger) and shell does not consider parameters as redirects but rather shell passes all parameters to program. Is it important to write command in two lines - how to represent in one?

Comment: Did you type the backslash at the end of the first line? The whole thing is logically one line. You can write it on one line (but then omit the backslash) like this: `~/openthread/output/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ot-ncp-ftd 1 
> /dev/pts/2 < /dev/pts/2`

Comment: Thank you. Yes - I copy-pasted with slash. I tried as one line without slash - the same result. Maybe spaces matter? swaping < and > gives no error but I dodn't know whether it changes semantics - but set of tested processes do not work as expected

Comment: What do these < and > mean - send output to /dev/pts/2 and receive input from /dev/pts/2 ?

Comment: What does "doesn't give correct result" mean? Do you get an error, does the program crash, does it run but produce unexpected results? What are the expected results?Please edit the question and add that information.

Comment: Unix programs have three IO streams automatically assigned to them: standard input (normally associated with keyboard input), standard output (normally associated with terminal screen output) and standard error output (normally also associated with terminal screen output). The input redirection operator `<` associates the given file (`/dev/pts/2`) in your example to standard input: instead of the input coming from the keyboard, it comes from the given file instead (btw, on Unix "everything is a file" - that's no longer as true as it used to be, but still: in particular, ...

Comment: ...devices like /dev/pts/2 are represented as "special" files in the file system). The output redirection operator associcates the standard output stream to the given file (in your case also '/dev/pts/2'). I'm not sure this is particularly helpful, but it's the best that I can do in one paragraph.

Comment: Question contains description of error: but I can repeat: this "redirection staff" should be consumed by shell. Instead all this params are passed to arguments of program.

Comment: What happens if you execute `echo foo > bar`?

Comment: @NickD Everybody knows about standard streams: as programmer I understand this - I'm not familiar with shell nuances: spaces, order of <, > - does it matter... Why reordering removes of error.

Comment: @NickD  Nothing happens - no output. file bar is created. If you are going to demonstrate how redirection works - please save time. If you try to verify something special in my system - I can perform this commands

Comment: OK - that's the way it should be (but there should a file named `bar` in the current directory and if you say `cat bar` the contents should be `foo`). But that is exactly the same syntax that your command uses to redirect its input and its output: does `/dev/pts/2` exist? What does `ls -l /dev/pts/2` give you? BTW, this is getting long and we might have to move to a chat room soon (unless somebody figures out what is wrong and provides an answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107516/discussion-between-nickd-and-vlad-kaponir).

Comment: Usually man has two choices: either spend 30 minutes to read manual or save time and create question with very precise description. I need to save time - I have deadline on Monday. Please help if you can or save our time. Nothing to discuss - I need solution

Comment: Sorry I can't help.

Comment: The only thing to discuss is to explain that program has main entry point. And program obtains parameters from OS: main(argv, argc); My program receives ALL this redirection staff - but I believe it souldn't. So likely shell doesn't interpret this as redirection.

Comment: That's correct: it shouldn't - all of that is handled by the shell before the program is exec'ed.

Comment: ot-ncp-ftd 1 < /dev/pts/2 > /dev/pts/2 interpreted better - The whole chain still doesn't work - but at least shell consumes redirection and program does not see them. Why reordering matters? And all this stuff is described above... :) When people see low score they stop reading question and start asking their questions... :)

Comment: Reordering does not matter.

Comment: Thank you. I enter command literally as it provided hear - is spaces here Ok?

Comment: You mean in the command `ot-ncp-ftd 1 < /dev/pts/2 > /dev/pts/2`? You can add spaces wherever there are spaces already; you can put the input redirection `< /dev/pts/2` before the command, between the command and the output redirection, or after the output redirection. Similarly, you can put the output redirection `> /dev/pts/2` anywhere you want. It does not make any difference.

Comment: @NickD Thank you! This is what I want to know. After reboot I couldn't reproduce this issue. It just works.

Comment: @NickD -  I reformulated my question: "Order and spaces in shell command using std input/output redirections."